# Using Accelerated Mobile Pages (amp) in thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, amp-html

I need to use AMP technology with specific pages in a (Spring MVC + thymeleaf) website, following the guides on [Create Your First AMP Page](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/get_started/create_page.html)

the validator shows many errors:

- The attribute 'xmlns' may not appear in tag 'html ⚡ for top-level
  html.
- The tag 'head > style[amp-boilerplate] - old variant' is deprecated -
  use 'head > style[amp-boilerplate]' instead.
- The mandatory text (CDATA) inside tag 'head > style[amp-boilerplate]  old variant' is missing or incorrect.

code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html amp xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" lang="ar">
<head>
  <title>Some title</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="canonical" content="some-url-here" />
  <style amp-boilerplate="">body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style>
  <script async="" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
content is here
</body>
</html>
```

any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Is the code above the output? If so, can you provide your source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the best way is to implement a different, light way version of ur page

for example: CNN has refereed to the amp version
view the source of this page:
http://edition.cnn.com/2017/01/31/politics/donald-trump-supreme-court-announcement/index.html

and here is the amp version
https://amp.cnn.com/cnn/2017/01/31/politics/donald-trump-supreme-court-announcement/index.html

So, for me I'll implement a new page without using thymeleaf

Answer (score 0):

You can use the xmlns tags without problems because the page renders itself without those. When you validate the page copy the html to validate from your browser, not from your IDE. With Chrome right click --> view page source gives you the clean html.